# How to use my API's response.data and format it into a usable array in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and the Pokemon API (https://pokeapi.co/) to make a simple web app where the user can search pokemons by name and filter by type.

I successfully implemented the searching for my own data.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

        contactData: [
            { name: 'Abet', phone: '010-0000-0001' },
            { name: 'Betty', phone: '010-0000-0002' },
            { name: 'Charlie', phone: '010-0000-0003' },
            { name: 'David', phone: '010-0000-0004' }
        ]

    };
}
```

With the contactData that I have, I successfully search the data that contains the keyword.

```
 render() {

        const mapToComponents = (data) => {
            //data.sort();

            data = data.filter(
                (contact) => {
                    return contact.name.toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(this.state.keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                }
                )

          return data.map((contact, i) => {
            return (<ContactInfo contact={contact} key={i}/>);
          });
        };

        return(


            <div className="Home">

                <input
                name = "keyword"
                placeholder = "Search"
                value = { this.state.keyword }
                onChange = { this.handleChange }
                />
                <div className="info">{ mapToComponents(this.state.contactData)}</div>

            </div>
        )
    }
```

My question is, I am not sure how to do the same thing with my response data from the Pokemon API. My response data looks like this in the console:

```
{count: 811, previous: null, results: Array(20), next: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20"}
count
:
811
next
:
"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20"
previous
:
null
results
:
Array(20)
0
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/", name: "bulbasaur"}
1
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/", name: "ivysaur"}
2
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/", name: "venusaur"}
3
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/", name: "charmander"}
4
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/", name: "charmeleon"}
5
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/", name: "charizard"}
6
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/", name: "squirtle"}
7
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/", name: "wartortle"}
8
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/", name: "blastoise"}
9
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10/", name: "caterpie"}
10
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/", name: "metapod"}
11
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/12/", name: "butterfree"}
12
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/13/", name: "weedle"}
13
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/14/", name: "kakuna"}
14
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/15/", name: "beedrill"}
15
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/16/", name: "pidgey"}
16
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/17/", name: "pidgeotto"}
17
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/18/", name: "pidgeot"}
18
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/19/", name: "rattata"}
19
:
{url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/20/", name: "raticate"}
length
:
20
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
```

How can format this like the contactData that I've created and display it for searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need one method to `fetch` data from `API` like this:

```
loadData() {
  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(items => this.setState({ data: items })
}
```

Then create another method `componentDidMount` and pass *loadData()*:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.loadData()
}
```

From official **React** documentation:

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

More information here: [React Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

**JSFiddle** example:

```js
class Data extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: []
      };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
     this.loadData()
  }

  // Fetch data from API:
  loadData() {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/`)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(items => this.setState({data: items}))
  }
  
  render() {
  
  const mapToComponents = data => {
    // Your logic...
    // Here you can use data...
  };
    
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Pokemon's:</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.data.results !== undefined ?
           this.state.data.results.map((x, i) => <li key={i}>{x.name}</li>) 
           : <li>Loading...</li>
          }
        </ul>

        <h1>THIS.STATE.DATA:</h1>

        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2)}
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Data />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```